# how to show a error when the textbox is empty

Tags: vb.net

How to show a error when the textbox is empty

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numofmon As Integer
    numofmon = TextBox4.Text
    If TextBox4.Text = ?? Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error")

    End If
End Sub
```

please help

Comment: as Icemanind suggested, this is certainly one route. the other is to use a ErrorProvider control to do the validation :): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you probably want to check `TextBox4.Text` before you try to assign its value to `numofmon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse an Integer value, so better that cheking if the textbox text is empty, directly you should call the `Integer.TryParse` function to evaluate whether the text, emptyness or not, could be translated as Integer value.

```
Dim numofmon As Integer

If Not (Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, numofmon)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error")

Else
    ' Logic here...

End If
```

Note that `numofmon` is passed by refference, so if `Integer.TryParse` success then it assigns the value to the given variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text) Then
    ' String is empty. Do something
End If
```

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is by using a Error Provider. Google it you will get many [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/658934/Error-Provider-Control-in-Windows-Application-Form). 
If you agree, please mark it as an answer.